# Spring Security JWT Token

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring security to authenticate login, I configure the Spring security in securityContext.xml

```
 <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_DEV-TEAM')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/customerMgt/customers/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADD-COMPANY')" />

    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/main" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1"/>
    <session-management />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
    <!--remember-me /--> <!-- AlexR: I did not have much luck with it in the past and IMO it presents security risk under strict DOD, etc. requirements -->
</http>

<beans:bean name="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
            user-search-base="ou=Users"
            group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
            group-search-base="ou=Groups"
            group-role-attribute="cn"
            role-prefix="ROLE_">
```

The Ldap will be replace by Database
Instead of setting the token in session and redirect the client i want to create a custom JWT with  Token and send it back to the client

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security does not have out-of-the-box support for token authentication. It is however very much doable. You will need to provide your own implementation of the following:

- `TokenAuthenticationFilter` - authenticates JWT token provided in a request header for every request. Replace BasicAuthenticationFilter with it.
- `LoginController` - authenticates given credentials and places a JWT token in the response header
- `JWTAuthenticationService` - handles token creation, encryption, decryption and validity check. Used by the two above.

When using token authentication, your security context should be stateless and each request gets authenticated by the `TokenAuthenticationFilter`. Therefore, configure http security to `stateless` session management and a `http403forbiddenentrypoint`.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use the spring-security-jjwt https://github.com/wnameless/spring-security-jjwt.

BTW, I am the author of this library. It provides the JWT security service which meets your requirements.